# check a background treatment process in ksh

Tags: ksh

How to test continuously and in the background if a treatment is in error.
if error i will send an error mail

Answer (score 0):

The wrong method IMHO is running a background process that will test and sleep and test and ...   That is terrible for the system administrator (what is going on on the system), you need additional actions (start after reboot) and what to do when your proc stops? Perhaps have another one that checks your prog?
Use crontab. Tell how often to check and all goes well (when `cron` works and your useraccount isnt blocked).
Make some check that one instance of the tester is finished before starting another one (something like a pid-file). And look for the best way to send mail.

Comment: thanks,
there is an other solution other than using `cron`?

Comment: You can write a script that will `while true; do sleep 10; do_some_test; done` but when do you start and stop this? Perhaps in the same script that starts your treatment.